# Probability Homework Help

Tags: probability, self-study

Consider that the probability of rejecting a governmental fund for a small business in a city is 4%. If the business is large, the probability that its fund will be rejected is 12%. Assume that 90% of businesses in this city are small.

a) what is the probability that business fund in this city will be rejected?

I feel like this is too simple, but would it not just be 4% + 12% = 16% chance that a business fund will be rejected regardless of size?

Answer (score 1):

90% * 4% - probability that the business is small and gets rejected
10% * 12% - probability that the business is large and gets rejected

the sum of the values is the answer
= 0.9*0.04 + (1-0.9)*0.12

Comment: I got 0.372 (37.2% a business will fail). Additionally, if a business fails, would the probability of it being a large business be 10% / 37.2%?

Comment: No, the answer is 0.036 + 0.012 = 0.048 (4.8%)

Comment: oops, thank you. I multiplied by 0.4, not 0.04

Comment: For the second part you need to use Bayes' formula: I believe it should be probability of rejected and being large (0.12)*(0.1) divided by total probability of being rejected (regardless of size) which is 0.048

Comment: what if it were reversed? if a business fund is approved, what's the chance of it being a small business? there would be a 95.2% chance of any size business being approved right? multiplied by 90% of business being small

Comment: yeah, so you need to divide probability of the project being small and approved (0.9 * 0.96) by 0.952

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Law of Total Probability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_total_probability):

$$
P(reject) = P(reject | small) P(small) + P(reject | large) P(large).
$$